# Can a mirage cause the hull of a ship to disappear before the sails?

Tags: optics, earth

["Mirage-effect" helps researchers hide objects](https://www.iop.org/news/11/oct/page_52313.html#gref)

The article linked above describes how the effect can be used to make an object disappear.

I am looking into flat earther beliefs and stumbled upon one of them claiming that it is the mirage effect that causes a ship's hull to disappear before the sails.I reason that this can't be given that eventually, you can't see the whole ship and this happens all the time, regardless of conditions. But I would still like to know whether the mirage effect could possibly cause the hull to disappear before the sails. I tried coming up with scenarios when this could happen, but I do not think any of them are practical.

Any illustrations will be helpful.

Comment: I've personally seen "mirage" effects over water many times, including a section of cliffs on the opposite shore line about 12 miles distant as well as ships of all sizes. The answer is "sort of yes" - but the mirage effects have always been very unstable "wavering" images, and look nothing like the non-mirage appearance of a ship disappearing below the horizon.

Comment: Making the hull disappear and making the hull appear to be going below the horizon aren't necessarily the same thing.  We expect the latter on a curved Earth, but your question seems to be asking about the more general former wording.  Was this intentional?

Comment: @JMac, yes. My question is about generally just making the hull disappear.